# kotlin android junit4 parameterized test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, instrumented-test

i got an issue,

i try to do a multi argument parameterized test with junit for instrumented test:

```
    @RunWith(Parameterized::class)
    class PileAddEditTopbarColorTest(
        private val testedPile: WoodPile
        private val testedColor: Color
    ) {
        @get:Rule
        val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

        companion object {
            @JvmStatic
            @Parameterized.Parameters
            fun testCase() = listOf(
                arrayOf(invalid_pile, redColor),
                arrayOf(valid_pile, GciGreen)
            )
        }
    }
```

when i try to run my test i got the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of arguments; expected 3, got 2

i try multiple thing, lot of time googling but i can'T figure what i did wrong,

when i do the test using only 1 argument:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized::class)
    class PileAddEditTopbarColorTest(
        private val testedPile: WoodPile
    ) {
        @get:Rule
        val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

        companion object {
            @JvmStatic
            @Parameterized.Parameters
            fun testCase() = listOf(
                invalid_pile,
                valid_pile
            )
        }
```

it's working

thank you for your help!